# Coordinated motion of objects on a grid

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, recreational-mathematics

This is the problem:

I have 9 objects on a 3 $\times$ 3 grid. They move simultaneously to an adjacent node on the grid (an object in the center can move to any of the other nodes on the grid, an object on one of the corners can move in three possible directions, etc). Which branch(es) of mathematics should I be studying in order to prove that it's possible for all of the objects on the grid to move without colliding (overlapping) with another object on the grid and come up with an algorithm to dictate how the objects can move on the grid given the direction of a single object on the grid?

Note: I'm a junior software engineer trying to code functionality into a game, not a mathematician. I've started with game theory (because its the math of decision making) and graph theory (because my problem can be visually represented as a graph with 9 nodes and 20 edges). I understand the topics that I am asking about could be over my head (currently). Please be patient. Also, has this exact problem (or a very similar problem) been solved yet?

Comment: I don't understand. You just need to print all of the possible moves for the other $8$ objects?

Comment: There is a really simple algorithm in time $9!$ would this be acceptable?

Comment: How exactly would I do that? Working in C# (unity) btw.

Comment: I get that 9! Give all possible combinations of moves, but how to determine algorithm  that dictates motion?

Comment: you can build the graph with the adjacency lists, label the vertices $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ like the buttons in a calculator.

Comment: Given the constraints stated in the text

Comment: I was wondering if there was a more concise algorithm than that...nice to know i was on the right track with graph theory tho

Comment: what does concise mean? there is a faster method with dancing links.

Comment: Surely there are only 16 possible moves? The center object has 8 choices where to go. The object which it displaces has two choices of which way to go around the outer cycle. Everything else is forced.

Comment: by concise, im asking for an equation or set of equations that for a given set of objects, the algorithm will dictate how all the objects will move given a chosen object's direction. The assumptions being the graph has 9 nodes and 20 edges (that kinda look like four squares with X's in them) and the objects are not allowed to cross paths with any other object while moving.

Comment: @Kundor my phone isn't allowing me to upload images, but I think the description my last comment could help

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo given the way I'm thinking about this, I'd have to encode for all possible paths for each node explicitly. I was wonder if there was a way around this. Maybe convert the graph into a large matrix and do some linear algebra and get a set of linear equations that dictate evrything? What do you think?

Comment: @Kundor are you taking into account that the nodes on the sides of the grid (not the corners) have 5 degrees?

Comment: yes, although that is only superficial, you can build the code to work for any graph.

Comment: @Joel: if a side piece goes to an adjacent side, the corner it passes is trapped and can't move. So none of those edges can actually be used.

Comment: wait what? the corner can't move? why?

Comment: @Kundor lets say the 9 nodes are labeled 0 - 8, where you have 0, 1,  and 2 in one row, 3, 4, and 5 in one row, and 6,7 and 8 in the last. If the object in space 3 moves to space 1, the object at space 0 can move to space 3, it isn't trapped (the object at space 1 can move to 0).

Comment: So then the objects trajectories can't "cross"?

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo correct

Comment: @Joel: Got it.${}$

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, graph theory is going to be what you're after. As an example of how graph theoretic tools can help, consider the following example results (with verbose proofs as you said this is not a familiar topic) that one might use graph theory to demonstrate.

> **Proposition**: There is no way of simultaneously moving all 9 objects if they may only move in cardinal directions (no diagonal moves).

*Proof*: Consider each square in your board a vertex; two vertices share an edge if and only if an object in one has an allowable move to the other (note this relation under the rules in  is symmetric so this is well defined). The resulting graph resembles a $3$x$3$ grid.

Then a collection of simultaneous moves for all objects (one starting on each node) within the allowable moveset is equivalent to looking for a directed cycle that hits each node exactly once (a so-called Hamiltonian cycle).

Color the nodes on your graph like a chess board.  Then any Hamiltonian cycle must take each black node to a white node (due to the limitations of objects only being able to move one square and only in cardinal directions) and vice versa. Thus any Hamiltonian cycle must connect an equal number of black and white nodes, and hence the total number of nodes must be even.  But we have 9 vertices so this is impossible, so such a cycle does not exist.

> **Corollary**: Under the movement rules in the initial question, in any allowable simultaneous movement of all $9$ pieces, at least one piece necessarily makes a diagonal move.

As for existence of such a simultaneous movement, it suffices to exhibit one: numbering from top-left to bottom-right in the order as one would read a book in:

$$1\to 2$$
$$2\to 3$$
$$3\to 6$$
$$6\to 5$$
$${\bf 5\to 9}$$
$$9\to8$$
$$8\to7$$
$$7\to 4$$
$$4\to 1$$
where the bolded move, $$5\to 9$$ is the requisite diagonal leap.

Comment: thx for the input. I was first put off by your proof because your argument is "Thing A must be true because the converse can't be". Then I thought about it and it makes sense, I'm convinced you're right. Now all I have to do is convert math into code and hope it works!

Comment: @JoelJ. Is your problem simply to return the list of all allowable moves of the 9 objects given the prescribed movement of one? Or is there some optimality criterion at play? (For example, given some pair of configurations of the board, what is the fewest moves to move from one to the other etc)

Comment: ideally, the algorithm will return one set of allowable moves from all possible moves given the prescribed movement of one. the only criteria that constrains movement is that the objects are not allowed to cross paths with other objects and objects must move to an adjacent node.